# Conceptual idea of "flux" of a vector field across or through a curve based on a concrete example

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

I am trying to understand the basic set up - the problem - behind line integration of vector fields, and I found this [great applet written by Matthias Kawski of the Mathematics Department at Arizona State University](https://math.la.asu.edu/~kawski/vfa2/) online, which [after much trouble installing](https://superuser.com/a/1312820/893385), allowed me to follow [this lecture](https://youtu.be/qCE5bmNlpi8?t=6m59s).

The applet shows the vector field given by 
$\tiny\begin{bmatrix}x^2\\y^2\end{bmatrix}$ as:

[image]

The applet allows the user to produce the *stacks*, orthogonal to the vector field arrows, corresponding to the differential 1-forms (covariant vectors):

[image]

and to draw an integration line manually as it calculates the [value of the line integral as circ on the right side of the panel](http://www.math.ups.edu/~martinj/m221vfanotes.html):

[image]

which amounts to $18.463980$ for this particular line. As the stacks are pierced they are nicely highlighted in green, giving a tactile intuition of what the integral is doing.

The question is about the **Flux** value also in the right panel, and in this case corresponding to $-1.462592.$ This is not so clearly defined in the linked instruction of the applet.

> If I can imagine the flux as water (or electricity) running through an infinitesimally small parallelogram on a surface with the velocity of flow corresponding to the vector field $\tiny\begin{bmatrix}x^2\\y^2\end{bmatrix}$, I don't see where the surface in question is being defined. On the other hand, $\tiny\begin{bmatrix}x^2\\y^2\end{bmatrix}$ can depict a surface, but then the vector field describing the velocity of water (or electricity) flowing through this surface is not defined.

I don't care about the applet per se, but in trying to understand what it is possibly being calculated, I attempt to see the set up for integration along a vector field.

---

**EDIT after comments: There is no "surface" in this example: just a curve (in red, below), instead, with the vector field indicating the velocity of some fluid flowing at each point on $\mathbb R^2$ (circ). The "flux" quantifies the flow orthogonal to the vector field:**

[image]

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: In two dimensions, the flux of a field across a curve is the integral of the dot product of the field with the **normal** vector to the curve. It measures how much the field flows *across* the curve, weighted by arclength. A conventional "line integral," by contrast, integrates the dot product of the field with the **tangent** vector of the curve; it measures how much the field flows *along* the curve, weighted by arclength. (Strictly speaking, "circulation" is a line integral around a *closed* curve, while "flux" doesn't require the curve to be closed.)

Comment: PS: your title has awkward language. We don't speak of the flux "through a vector field," but rather the flux *of* a vector field *across* or *through* a curve (in two dimensions) or surface (in three dimensions).

Comment: @symplectomorphic That helps... So there is really **no** surface defined by $\begin{bmatrix}x^2&y^2\end{bmatrix}^T$ in the context of my original question. It would still be very useful to see the equations that the applet is resolving in some random point. As for the title, I'll try to edit it, but if you see a better way to word it, just go ahead...

Comment: I don't want to look at this movie. Why don't you just ask about "flux in two dimensions"? symplectomorphic has given a fine answer, unfortunately in the comments.

Comment: I agree that symplectomorphic has already answered my question. The movie is just for context - no need to watch it.